# What is the equivalent of "OnIdle" in WPF

Tags: wpf

What is the best way to perform something when an application is idle?

Should I use DispatcherTimer?

Or BeginInvoke?

Comment: More context please. What do you want to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be this.

In a DispatcherObject (such as a Window or UserControl):

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => SomeMethod()), DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);
```

Comment: -1 One-off method invoking is not a continuous means to processing "on idle"

Answer (score 7):

You should use a [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) with a [DispatcherPriority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx) set to either `DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle` or `DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle` (depending on your goals).

Answer (score 4):

I think the use of Dispatcher.Hooks.DispatcherInactive should be the closest equivalent to OnIdle event:

[DispatcherHooks.DispatcherInactive Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherhooks.dispatcherinactive.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do idle processing in XAML

```
    DispatcherTimer timerIdle;
    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Create our idle timer.
        timerIdle = new DispatcherTimer
            (
            TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
            DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle,
            (s, b) => {
                timerIdle.Stop();
                *************SOME FUNCTION HERE*****************
            },
            Application.Current.Dispatcher
            );

        //Start the timer here
        timerIdle.Start();
    }

    private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       if(!timerIdle.IsEnabled)
          timerIdle.Start();
    }
```